# Write PySpark 2.0.1 DataFrame as PostgreSQL table: UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: postgresql, unicode, dataframe, pyspark

I've got the following error when trying to write a spark DataFrame as a PostgreSQL table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-159b38b4c333> in <module>()
      7         "password":"112211234",
      8         "driver":"org.postgresql.Driver",
----> 9         "client_encoding":"utf8"
     10     }
     11 )

/home/ec2-user/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.pyc in jdbc(self, url, table, mode, properties)
    760         for k in properties:
    761             jprop.setProperty(k, properties[k])
--> 762         self._jwrite.mode(mode).jdbc(url, table, jprop)
    763 
    764 

/home/ec2-user/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/ec2-user/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/home/ec2-user/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

<type 'str'>: (<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'An error occurred while calling o3418.jdbc.\n: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 105.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 105.0 (TID 1937, 10.0.0.52): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: \u041f\u043e\u0434\u0441\u043e\u0435\u0434\u0438\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043f\u043e \u0430\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0443 localhost:5432 \u043e\u0442\u043a\u043b\u043e\u043d\u0435\u043d\u043e. \u041f\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0440\u044c\u0442\u0435 \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0445\u043e\u0441\u0442 \u0438 \u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442 \u0443\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u044b \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e \u0438 \u0447\u0442\u043e postmaster \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442 TCP/IP-\u043f\u043e\u0434\u0441\u043e\u0435\u0434\u0438\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f.\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:52)\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:216)\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
```

The DataFrame is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row, DataFrame, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "test") \
    .getOrCreate()

fields = [
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("age", IntegerType(), True)
]
schema = StructType(fields)

test = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(id=1, name=u"a", age=34), 
    Row(id=2, name=u"b", age=25)
], schema)

test.show()
```

i.e. this one

```
+---+----+---+
| id|name|age|
+---+----+---+
|  1|   a| 34|
|  2|   b| 25|
+---+----+---+
```

To write it to PostgreSQL I use the code:

```
test.write.jdbc(
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db", 
    table="test", 
    mode="overwrite", 
    properties={
        "user":"root", 
        "password":"12345", 
        "driver":"org.postgresql.Driver", 
        "client_encoding":"utf8"
   }
)
```

But it generates the error shown above. Cannot find the reason of this exception.

The reading of an existing table created using postres console works fine.

I will be grateful any help.

Comment: It's usually better to include your error message as text,for it to be indexable by search engines.

Comment: The problem is solved. The reason was in the incorrect localisation in PostgreSQL and on of cluster's workers.